# Cron job break other foreground server in docker

Tags: cron, docker, dockerfile, docker-compose

In order to start selenium server on start,

I have to put `entry_point.sh` under `/opt/bin`

but if I uncomment the cron command  `CMD cron  && tail -f /var/log/cron.log`

The server won't run anymore.

I couldn't figure out why it will be broken

## This is my cron file

```
SHELL=/usr/bin/zsh
* * * * * echo $PATH >> /root//reboot_record.txt >> /tmp/cron_debug_log.log 2>&1
* * * * * cd /home/poc/lazy-bird/j && ruby j.rb >> /tmp/cron_debug_log.log 2>&1
* * * * * echo $PATH >> /root//reboot_record.txt >> /tmp/cron_debug_log.log 2>&1
* * * * * cd /home/poc/lazy-bird/p && ruby p.rb >> /tmp/cron_debug_log.log 2>&1
```

## This is my docker file

```
#====================================
# Scripts to run cron job
#====================================
# Add crontab file in the cron directory
ADD cron_lazy_bird /etc/crontab
# Create the log file to be able to run tail
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log
# Use the crontab file
RUN crontab /etc/crontab
# Run the command on container startup
#CMD cron  && tail -f /var/log/cron.log
#====================================
# Scripts to run Selenium Standalone
#====================================
COPY entry_point.sh /opt/bin/entry_point.sh
RUN chmod +x /opt/bin/entry_point.sh
USER seluser
EXPOSE 4444
USER root
CMD ["/bin/bash", "/opt/bin/entry_point.sh"]
```

## UPDATE  entry_point.sh

```
cron  && tail -f /var/log/cron.log

export GEOMETRY="$SCREEN_WIDTH""x""$SCREEN_HEIGHT""x""$SCREEN_DEPTH"

xvfb-run --server-args="$DISPLAY -screen 0 $GEOMETRY -ac +extension RANDR" \
    java -jar /opt/selenium/selenium-server-standalone.jar \
    -role node \
    -hub http://$HUB_1_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR:$HUB_1_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT/grid/register \
    -browser browserName=firefox
```

Answer (score 0):

Your entrypoint script needs to be called from either the `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD` instruction, or it won't get run when the container is started.

You'll need to remove the `CMD` and start cron from the entrypoint script before launching the application. You might want to use a process manager such as runit or supervisord to handle this (see https://docs.docker.com/articles/using_supervisord/).

Comment: thanks, but i tried your solution , it may not work, the process will stuck at `cron` and not running the `xvfb-run` server.

Comment: So, as I suggested, use a process manager to start cron: https://docs.docker.com/articles/using_supervisord/ or you can just go the hacky root and start cron in the background.

Comment: (to start cron in the background, just add an & to the end of the line)